# How to fix RTools so that I can download R Packages?

Tags: r, rtools

I recently updated by RStudio to the latest version and now get the following error whenever I install an R package that states the following:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently 
installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of 
Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
```

I have visited the website and downloaded RTools 4.3 in the default location as suggested. I've reloaded R, restarted my PC, but I am still getting the same error message. Does anyone know what's causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: Once you downloaded it, did you actually install it into Windows? Double click the `.exe` file, then restart R (and RStudio) so that it can recognize the newly installed tools.

Comment: FYI, upgrading RStudio has no impact on the installation of R packages. I'm guessing that you recently updated *R*, and updating the programming language is far different from updating the development environment (IDE) known as RStudio. I've removed the [tag:rstudio] tag; if this is in error and installation works from `Rgui.exe` but not from within RStudio, my apologies, we can re-add the tag.

Comment: While the dupelink states specific R and Rtools versions, the answer is still applicable for recent versions of both. If you go through the steps (including restarting both R and RStudio) and you still cannot get it to work, please @-ping me and we'll see what else is wrong. Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: Worked it out... I'd downloaded it to my SSD instead of HDD. Thanks for your help :)